# Why does the second array gets modified?

Tags: arrays, perl

I just want to assign the value of the AB array to the last position of the ABU array.

```
$ABU->[1][-1][1] = $AB->[1][$i][1];
```

And every time this assignation occurs, the AB array gets modified.

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $lenghtf; $i++) {
        if ($ABU->[1][-1][1] < $AB->[1][$i][0]) {
            push (@{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][$i]);
        } elsif ($ABU->[1][-1][1] < $AB->[1][$i][1]){
            $ABU->[1][-1][1] = $AB->[1][$i][1];
        }
    }
```

If I do

```
print Dumper ($AB[1]);
```

before the loop and

```
print Dumper {ABU => $ABU, AB => $AB};
```

after the loop, I get this output:

![enter image description here][1]

After people's answers, I have realised that the problem may be when I assign the first value to ABU[1] before the loop:

```
push (@{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][0]);
```

If I do print with dumper before the loop:

[image]

I've tried to change that firs asignation syntax:

```
push (@{$ABU->[1]}, @{$AB->[1][0]});
```

And then the Dumper looks better:

[image]

The problem now is that I don't know why when I run the for loop it complains in the first if line:

```
if ($ABU->[1][-1][1] < $AB->[1][$i][0]) {
```

with this STDERR:

Can't use string ("15") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"

Comment: The code looks valid.. Please provide some realistic data for the arrays, so we can try to reproduce.

Comment: if I print the AB[1] array before the loop:
([3,15],[10,22],[81,99],[85,98][90,110])

if I print the AB[1] array after the loop:
([3,22],[10,22],[81,110],[85,98][90,110])

Comment: Are portions of `$ABU`'s datastructure shared by `$AB`'s datastructure?  If you copy a reference the copy refers to the same thing that its source did.

Comment: if I print the ABU[1] array after the loop:
([3,22],[81,110])

Comment: After the loop, add `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper {ABU => $ABU, AB => $AB};` I'm guessing you'll see duplicate references.

Comment: I'll put it this way: There is nothing in the code you posted that would cause `$AB` to be modified.  However, assigning to some part of `$ABU` could overwrite a part of `$AB` if the data-structures overlap, sharing the same references somewhere along the way. You haven't shown how the datastructures are created, but I suspect elsewhere in your code you have managed to construct two datastructures that share some of the same references.

Comment: But you are incorrect in thinking that this is the code that is the cause of your problem. This code is only exposing the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I guess what you mean, but I still do not know where this overlapping happens... I posted the output of print dumper... Maybe you can explain me the output final part... Sorry for my inexperience

Comment: Those `$VAR1->...` lines embedded in the Dumper output indicate that those elements share a reference with an earlier portion of Dumper's output.  Somewhere along the way you have assigned a reference to another structure, rather than a deep clone of the reference's structure.

Comment: so, what do you mean with  rather than a deep clone of the reference's structure? I cannot find where I could assign a reference to another structure

Comment: in case you didn't follow what other people are saying:  the code you show is not where the problem is; the problem is in the code that is building $AB and $ABU earlier.  somewhere in that code you have an error that is making `$AB[0][1][0]` the same array reference as `$ABU[1][0]` and `$AB[0][1][2]` the same array reference as `$ABU[1][1]`.  show that code and we can suggest how to fix it.  without showing that code, we can't help much.

Comment: Thanks a lot everybody. I think the problem happens when I assign the first value of the ABU[1] array before the loop: 

push (@{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][0]);

I've tried to do this:

push (@{$ABU->[1]}, @{$AB->[1][0}]);

And then I stop seeingn the references $VAR1->... in the Dumper printing.

The problem now is that it complains inside the loop in the first if line:

Can't use string ("15") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line

```
push (@{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][$i]);
```

Here you clearly insert a reference to the array. It will be seen at result of `print Dumper {ABU => $ABU, AB => $AB};` which is missing in your question. But it can be seen in the next image.

[image]

See this `$VAR->{ABU}[1][0]`. After few cycles, you will end up with multiple references to the same array.

For your data format, you can do

```
push @{$ABU->[1]}, [@{$AB->[1][$i]}];
```

But using some cloning routine would be more robust (immune to the feature code changes which inevitably come with time).

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
push @{$ABU->[1]}, dclone($AB->[1][$i]);
```

BTW your code could be written

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
for my $ab_row (@{$AB->[1]}) {
    my $last_abu_row = $ABU->[1][-1];
    if ($last_abu_row->[1] < $ab_row->[0]) {
        push @{$ABU->[1]}, dclone($ab_row);
    } elsif ($last_abu_row->[1] < $ab_row->[1]) {
        $last_abu_row->[1] = $ab_row->[1];
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

The expression `push @{$ABU->[1]}, [@{$AB->[1][$i]}];`:

`$AB->[1][$i]` is array reference

`@{$AB->[1][$i]}` is content of array refrenced by `$AB->[1][$i]`

`[@{$AB->[1][$i]}]` is array reference to fresh new array with content of array referenced by `$AB->[1][$i]`. It is shorthand of:

```
do {
    my @array;                # fresh new array
    @array = @{$AB->[1][$i]}; # Here you copy content of array
    \@array;                  # return reference to the new array
}
```

Then you push it to the array referenced by `$ABU->[1]`. After this statement `$ABU->[1][-1]` contains array reference to the new array with content copied from array referenced by `$AB->[1][$i]`.

In contrast `push @{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][$i];`

`$AB->[1][$i]` is array reference

which you push into the array referenced by `$ABU->[1]`. So you push array reference referencing the original array. In other words, after the statement `$ABU->[1][-1] = $AB->[1][$i]`, the same array reference.

The third statement `push @{$ABU->[1]}, @{$AB->[1][$i]};` will push content of array referenced by `$AB->[1][$i]`. It means you don't add one new element to the array referenced by `$ABU->[1]` but same amount of elements as `@{$AB->[1][$i]}` contains. It breaks reference but doesn't do what you want. You could fix it this way:

```
push @{$ABU->[1]}, [];
push @{$ABU->[1][-1]}, @{$AB->[1][$i]};
```

but it is less elegant way of writing `push @{$ABU->[1]}, [@{$AB->[1][$i]}];`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I wouldn't like to take up your time, but if you don't mind, could you explain me why this subtil change on the syntax of the push function, solved my problem? I mean, what is the difference between : push @{$ABU->[1]}, [@{$AB->[1][0]}]; , push (@{$ABU->[1]}, $AB->[1][0]); and  push (@{$ABU->[1]}, @{$AB->[1][0}]);

Comment: @PauRS: See **Edit**.

Comment: Thank you very much.I greatly appreciate your extended answer. It helped me a lot to really understand deeply the references usage.

Answer (score 1):

You are non showing so much code. Maybe both $ABU and $AB are references to same array.

Comment: No, they aren't. The references are the subroutine arguments. The script is very long and I'm sure that the code I've posted has the responsible part for my problem. But I don't know why that assignation produces a change on the AB array.

Comment: @PauRS "*I'm sure that the code I've posted has the responsible part for my problem*" - it doesn't (and if you're so sure that's where the problem is, why do you need us?).

Comment: Sorry for my english, maybe it was to strong to say that I'm sure. What I mean is that if that assignation occurs, the AB changes, if I remove it of my script, AB stays as originally.

Comment: Why not print both without Using `Dumper` and check the `memory address` if both are pointing to the same `address`?